# SAS - Insert statement into existing SQL table

Tags: sql, insert, sas, dataset

Here is my code:

```
PROC SQL;
connect to odbc (dsn=ODC uid=sa pwd=XXXXX);
EXECUTE ( INSERT INTO dbo.tblDLA_Backup SELECT * FROM &dlafile.) BY ODBC;
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Im getting this error

> ERROR: CLI execute error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'work.dlabackup'.

If i do this:

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc (dsn=ODC uid=sa pwd=XXXXX);


insert into tblDLA_Backup SELECT * FROM WORK.DLABACKUP;

disconnect from odbc;
```

quit;

I get this error:

> ERROR: File WORK.TBLDLA_BACKUP.DATA does not exist.

Why is it that I can't reference my SAS dataset and just insert? it should be simple as that..

Comment: there is no `insert into..select..` in sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error occurs because you are executing an SQL instruction on *SQL Server*, and not *locally*. And since this instruction contains a reference to your local *SAS dataset*, an error occurs because SQL server thinks it is a table in its own database.

You take a wrong approach on that one.

Your second approach is correct because you are executing the SQL in SAS, which both knows the *local dataset* and the *SQL server tables*. And it is syntactically valid at first glance.

The error is clear: SAS doesn't found the local dataset `WORK.TBLDLA_BACKUP`

Thus, verify if this dataset exists and is not corrupted:

in your **explorer window**, click on **Libraries**, then **Work**, and verify if **TBLDLA_BACKUP** is there, and if yes open it and check if you see your data.

I can't say more at this point, but you should hopefully discover something.

Comment: Thank you! I realized I was confusing the error message saying my temp work.dlabackup table was missing, but actually it was the SQL table that needed a prefix, so I used libname statement and just added mysql.tbldla_backup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use libref it you want to write into the foreign database.

```
libname sqldb odbc dsn=ODC uid=sa pwd=XXXXX ;
PROC SQL;
  INSERT INTO SQLDB.tblDLA_Backup SELECT * FROM &dlafile.;
quit;
```

Note that you also need fix it so that your macro variable contains the name of a table that exists.